# not able to change priority level of Linux services into Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, init.d

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit Linux System and I created some Linux services into /etc/init.d directory which are started at system uptime.

so, I have assigned default priority to all my custom service using following commands.

> update-rc.d service_name defaults

Now, I want to assign different priority level to different services which should be started as per priority assigned.

So, I have assigned different priority levels using following command but i found that soft link created for each services are almost change means no any difference like S01 or S02 for all services.

> update-rc.d service_name start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 80 0 1 6 .

I have also checked boot-up logs and found that services are not started as per priority sequence which I assigned using above command.

So, does anyone has any idea or clue for this type of issue? Please let me know if anyone has faced this type of issue and resolved it using any configuration or something else.

Answer (score 0):

update-rc.d(8) enables or disables services, while the ordering of services is handled by insserv(8), and can be customized by editing the LSB header of the Tomcat service and setting/adding:

Required-Start: mysql

Further reference can be found https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. Recently, I've encountered the same issue and after some research, I've got the following conclusion: as of 16.04, ubuntu has no longer support start and stop in the update-rc.d arguments. Please see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

According to this answer from [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) @ "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311709/update-rc-d-ignoring-sequence-numbers",

> update-rc.d defaults doesn't process any other arguments; it uses
>   information from the init script's LSB headers to determine the
>   priority to use (the sequence number), and to determine in which
>   runlevels to start and stop the service.